# Would a cooking blowtorch be suitable for heating a seized nut?

Tags: screws

I've seen that one of the best ways to loosen a seized nut is to heat it with a blowtorch. I have a cooking blowtorch which claims to reach 1300C but also says "for cooking use only". Is there any reason it would not be suitable for DIY purposes?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is it is not built to handle the heat for longer periods of time.  You must be be aware of the materials around the nut so they do not catch on fire.  Using heat is usually last choice, bigger tools, penetrating oils, heat then big heat to melt the nut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely restrictive language from the legal department, so you don't win a lawsuit after blowing up your garage while trying to loosen a nut on the lawnmower with the gasoline leaking everywhere.

A torch is a torch. Use common sense so as not to get into a situation involving a lawsuit you'll lose due to violating manufacturer's instructions.

Comment: Probably more expensive also since cooking is on it.

Comment: ...All the professional chefs I know use a plumbing torch for their Creme Brulee toppings...

Comment: @crip659 au contraire